# Nested Input Problems

Tags: javascript, nested-function

why is "undefined" showing up on top of my text

```
function myname() {
    document.write('Im john doe ');
}

function myage() {
    myname();
    document.write('Im 47 years old');
}
document.querySelector('.test').innerHTML=myage();
```

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/cuhovijesa/edit?html,output) here's the full code

Comment: `myAge()` does not return anything, so the implicit value would be `undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myage(){
        myname();
        document.write('Im 47 years old')

    }
    document.querySelector('.test').innerHTML=myage()
```

In this when You are calling `myage()` it is not returning anything. So innerHtml for the Selected Target gets nothing.

This is the reason why it's showing Undefined.

Answer (score 0):

When the browser processes a HTML-document and comes across a  tag, it needs to execute before continuing building the DOM. As you are trying to access document.querySelector('.test') which is not available at that moment, it has given an undefined. Check out the below code where, the script gets executed with out undefined after the dom loads.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="test"></div>
</body>
<script>
    function myname(){
        document.write('Im john doe ')
    }
    function myage(){
        myname();
        document.write('Im 47 years old')
       
    }
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
   document.querySelector('.test').innerHTML=myage()
  });
  
  
    
</script>
</html>
```